# Failed to restart php-fpm.service: Unit php-fpm.service not found

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, fpm

My site showing error 502 Bad Gateway . on checking error log file i found error -
**connect() to unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client**

how can i fixed this issue ?

Comment: Can you post the output of `php -v`?

Comment: php 5.5.12 (cli)

Comment: Are you sure you actually have php fpm Installed?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Depending what version of `php-fpm` you are using, you need one of the following commands:

```
sudo service php5-fpm restart        // php 5.x
sudo service php7.0-fpm restart      // php 7.0.x
sudo service php7.1-fpm restart      // php 7.1.x
```

Comment: try with this but getting same error Failed to restart php5.5-fpm.service: Unit php5.5-fpm.service not found

Comment: For php5, you should always use `php5-fpm`

Comment: same error occurring

Comment: And for `php-7.1.12` i run  **`service php-fpm71 restart`**

Comment: on Centos 6 (especially if you are under CWP panel) for php-7.2 give a try:
`/bin/systemctl restart php-fpm72.service`

Comment: If you're running RHEL 7 like me, run **sudo service rh-php71-php-fpm restart**

Comment: @imin for me it was sudo service php71-php-fpm restart (RHEL 7)

Comment: not working for php 8, ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Well ofcourse not, this answer is 5 years old. You should use `sudo systemctl restart php8.0-fpm`.

Comment: @Jerodev Thanks it worked for me, I tried : lc2530hz:~$ sudo systemctl restart php8.1-fpm

Comment: You might need to install php fpm first

`sudo apt install php7.3-fpm`